# SWT TreeViewer Drag n Drop: SWTException Widget is disposed

Tags: java, exception, drag-and-drop, swt

I have a CTabFolder containing a few disposable tabs which contain a TreeViewer each. I want every Viewer to have a DragSupport. So naturally i used the method `TreeViewer#addDragSupport` for that. Everything works as expected, except when i close the shell and SWT tries to dispose all the widgets.

The Exception that occurs is:

```
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Widget is disposed
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.checkWidget(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.removeListener(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.dnd.DragSource.onDispose(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.dnd.DragSource.access$1(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.dnd.DragSource$2.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.dispose(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.dnd.DragSource$1.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.dispose(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ContentViewer.handleDispose(ContentViewer.java:172)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleDispose(StructuredViewer.java:2328)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ContentViewer$2.widgetDisposed(ContentViewer.java:214)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.dispose(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ContentViewer.handleDispose(ContentViewer.java:172)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleDispose(StructuredViewer.java:2328)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ContentViewer$2.widgetDisposed(ContentViewer.java:214)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.dispose(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ContentViewer.handleDispose(ContentViewer.java:172)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleDispose(StructuredViewer.java:2328)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ContentViewer$2.widgetDisposed(ContentViewer.java:214)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.dispose(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ContentViewer.handleDispose(ContentViewer.java:172)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleDispose(StructuredViewer.java:2328)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ContentViewer$2.widgetDisposed(ContentViewer.java:214)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.releaseChildren(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.releaseChildren(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.releaseChildren(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.dispose(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.dispose(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.dispose(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.close(Window.java:335)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.ApplicationWindow.close(ApplicationWindow.java:307)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.handleShellCloseEvent(Window.java:741)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window$3.shellClosed(Window.java:687)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.closeWidget(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.WM_CLOSE(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.windowProc(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowProc(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.callWindowProc(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.windowProc(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowProc(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.callWindowProc(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.windowProc(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowProc(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessageW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
```

which seems a bit extensive. It seems that SWT tries to remove the DragListener from the Tree after it had been disposed. I dont really understand how this is even possible.

I dont think that i made a mistake implementing the Source/Target and the Transfer type, since the dragging and dropping works like a charm.

Are there maybe any pitfalls to consider when adding a Drag Support to a TreeViewer which is contained in a disposable Widget?

If you need a Code example let me know.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't bee a problem. You have 2 options: write a piece of code that gives you that error or just add a dispose listener event on the Folder and remove the drag support there.